# Orion's Oracle DB

Tags: oracle

I've a strange question.I have got a document that a client send it to me.In that document he needs the following thing to be implemented

```
DISPLAY DETAILS FROM ORION: On click of this link connect to ORION’s
ORACLE. DBCREDENTIALS   and table structure will be provided by
client) and populate below grid(there is a grid below). Display Grid only 
if link is clicked.
```

i just could not understand it.What should i do to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they mean Orion, the I/O profiling tool?  If so, you can download it from OTN.  [Find it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-089595.html).  (Apparently it is included in the 11gR2 install in `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`.)

If you want to know anbout how to use Orion I suggest you have a read of [Tim Hall's Oracle-Base article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/MeasuringStoragePerformanceForOracleSystems.php).

Alternatively:

There is a data management company called [Orion Data Management](http://www.oriondm.com/).

There is a ERP product called [Orion](http://erp-software.findthebest.com/l/22/ORION-Enterprise).

For a while Oracle's J2EE solution OC4J was based on a prodcut they bought called [Orion App Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Application_Server).

It might be [a lovely dress for pregnant ladies](http://oriri.com.au/oracle-orion-drawstring-dress).

Finally, there is a New Age novel called [Orion's Oracle](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Orions-Oracle-Gary-B-Allison/dp/0595328652).

Aren't search engines a marvellous thing?

Comment: I installed it,but i have no idea on what should i do after that.I searched but in vain